# How to call Java implicit method inside the explicit one?

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app and I need to either perform some task or leave it for default operation on back button press, on certain condition met. Is it possible to call Java implicit method inside the explicit one? Or any other method is possible?
Thank u.

Comment: you can override onBackPresed() method and define your custom logic to do things inside onBackPresed method.

Comment: @HasanMohdKhan,   Thank u, but its not always override i want. I need to check condition and decide either to override or go with default back button operation

Comment: can you not just check the condition inside the overridden method? if conditions meet, do what ya want to do. If not, just call "super.x()" x() is whatever function you are overriding.

Comment: onBackPresed() is own my android framework classes so U can not define your own onBackPressed() method. overide on back press method and inside that method write your logic.

Comment: @CrazySports101. It is working. Thank you.